# get element id jquery on drop

Tags: javascript, html

I've found [a tutorial on w3schols](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp), that helped me with drag and drop, but I have a noob question:
How can I get `ev.target.id` from `drag(ev)` function?

Answer (score 0):

**DRAG:**

You can send the element itself as parameter:

```
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this)" width="336" height="69">
```

And in the JS:

```
function drag(ev, obj)
{
    alert(obj.id);
}
```

**DROP:**

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, this)"></div>
```

and JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev, obj)
{
    alert(obj.id);
}
```